# JavaScript to call a VBA routine with parameters

Tags: javascript, excel, hta, vba

1. I need to pass arguments to a Excel VBA code from JavaScript of HTA.

   1. I can successfully call VBA function, but unable to pass string arguments correctly.
   2. JavaScript function can pass different string arguments.
   3. Below is code in simple and demo form.
   4. Excel-VBA code

   ```
   Sub subTest(strName As String)
   MsgBox strName
   End Sub
   ```

HTA code with Javascript

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>HTA</title>
<hta:application 
id="oHta"
applicationname="htaNavi"
border="1"
borderstyle = normal
contextmenu = "yes"
caption="Navigator"
sysmenu="yes"
WINDOWSTATE="maximize"
>
</head>
<body>
<input type="button" value="testing" onclick="funRun('testng string')" />
<input type="button" value="testing second" onclick="funRun('testng')" />
</body>

<script>

var objExl;
var objWb;
var objExl =new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
objExl.Visible = true;
var objWb = objExl.Workbooks;
var strpath = '\path\testing_excel_web.xls';
objWb.Open(strpath);

function funRun(strName)
{
alert(strName);
objWb.Application.Run('testing_excel_web.xls!subTest(strName)');
}
</script>
</html>
```

I can call subTest, but message box populates strName as string but not 'testing string' as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm thinking you want:

```
objWb.Application.Run('testing_excel_web.xls!subTest("' + strName + '")');
```

This way, the value of the variable `strName` is concatenated to the command you are attempting to run.

I know nothing about this calling of a VBA function, so I'm not sure if you need the `"` around the `strName` like I provided or not.

In addition, to be safe, in case your `strName` value contains `"`, you should use this:

```
objWb.Application.Run('testing_excel_web.xls!subTest("' + strName.replace(/"/g, "\"") + '")');
```

Hopefully with this, the value of `strName` could be

```
The word "testing" here
or
"Here's a quote"
```

and it will still work.

The point is that if the string contains `"`, the Javascript would/could fail. If it would absolutely never contain `"`, then forget about it. But I think it's needed since any `"` in the value of `strName` will break the passing of it as a parameter.

Comment: Thanks for consideration. I tried that and got error : can't run the macro 'testing_excel_web.xls!subTest(testing string)'.

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved me from writing 100 lines of repetative code lines. I used to thought programming is all about using keywords, but . . . You guessed right problem was indeed with ""

Comment: Awesome, glad it helped! I had a feeling the quotes were needed. Anyways, I edited my answer to include a "safer" solution, in case the string contains a `"` itself. With my first solution, try passing your function the value `"asdf"`, and see if it still works...I don't think it will. If it doesn't, use my second solution. If you have any trouble/questions, let me know.

Comment: True. Just passing "asdf" as argument fails (Error : Unterminated string). But if used with your second method, it works. Thanks for proper explanation.