# adminLTE and VBscripts?

Tags: excel, vba, web-services, web, admin

My goal is to use adminLTE ([adminLTE)](https://almsaeedstudio.com/themes/AdminLTE/index2.html) interface in a corporate setting which allows for VBA scripts to run to automate task which my non-tech savy team can accomplish much quicker than by doing them by hand. (pre-filling emails, providing inventory information, creating and printing forms automatically, integrating with stamps.com,  reference and display a lot of excel data). From my understanding, the execution of VBA scripts in a web browser is not allowed.

1. What are my options for accomplishing my goal?
2. Do this in an HTA file?
3. Am I wrong about web browser executions of VB scripts?
4. Do I need to build an application in Visual Studio?

I have a team of three which need to access this and share data, so it's not like an entire enterprise spread across the nation or anything like that. Thanks.

Any and all thoughts are welcome.

Comment: I believe there is an obscure and unpopular way to do this using Microsoft's HTA technology but I wouldnt recommend it. Is your question how to execute VBA within an HTA? If so see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511109/javascript-to-call-a-vba-routine-with-parameters. If not please update your question.

Comment: Your question seems to be confusing VBA with VBscript?  If you mean the scripting language which can be run in IE or as a standalone script then that's VBscript.  VBA is the macro language used in the MS Office applications.  The two languages are syntactically similar but not the same thing.

Comment: Yes, you're right Tim. I ment to say VBscript. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This question is pretty broad - it's the same as asing "what are my options for executing an arbitrary EXE on an end user's computer from a browser." The whole point of browser based applications is to prevent this from happening for security reasons.

If your goal is to deploy VBA scripts to everyone in your organization - that's actually pretty easy - just create an automatically updating Excel addin. This approach is very common and easy to do (more info if needed).

To answer your questions:

1. Too broad
2. Yes you can do this in a HTA file but I don't recommend it and I don't think it does what you want.
3. You cannot run VBA within a browser in the traditional sense. An HTA from what I understand is essentially a desktop app that is written using HTML i.e. you couldn't deploy an HTA to example.com.
4. You can build a ASP.NET web app in Visual Studio and have your front end (e.g. Admin LTE) call an end point on the backend which then calls an EXE but that would be an EXE on the server and not the client.

Comment: You can deploy an HTA and serve it from a web server, but the end-user will be prompted has to allow it to run (and has to be running Windows of course).  It is basically a web application with elevated privileges, but it runs in MSHTA.exe and not in IE..

Comment: @Tim Williams - thanks for explaining. In my mind that's basically the same as having say a ClickOnce installer that runs when you go to a URL - it's not running in a browser it just using the browser to kick off a desktop installer.

Comment: Yes - you are right - more like ClickOnce, though I think it still counts as "deploy"