# Is it Possible to deal with excel though JavaScript web application

Tags: javascript, excel

Usually , the work deals with Excel sheet which becomes one of the necessaties in any business . My idea is to create web Application which its backend or source of data will be excel . if that possible , please share with me any material can help in starting this project .

Comment: Take a look at https://github.com/sheetjs/sheetjs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have a look to [spreadjs](https://www.grapecity.com/spreadjs)
Probabaly wont come with all the excel features but has got lost of features, demos and you can download a free trial for the main front-end frameworks.

Also you can wonder around the documentation to check formulas and the basic spreadsheet operations, and maybe check if some specific feature you are after is offered.

Another approach you can check out is to communicate VBA and Javascript, so that you can code an VBA API to be called so that you can retrieve the info you want from Javascript, of from the backend languaje of your choice. Not a tipycal use case, but seems it can be done. Check this [source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14511109/javascript-to-call-a-vba-routine-with-parameters) and this [source2](http://automatetheweb.net/)

Comment: I got it , Thanks a lot !